# What is the optimised way to get a count of keys in a riak bucket?

Tags: mapreduce, riak

I have a riak cluster set up with 3 servers. I can look at the bitcask to establish how much disk space this cluster is currently using but I'd also like to find out how many items are currently being stored in the cluster.

The cluster is being used to store images, meaning that binary data is being stored against a key in a set of buckets. I have tried to use map reduce functions against the HTTP interface in order to return the number of items in the bucket however they have timed out.

What is the most time optimised way to get the count of the number of keys from a specific bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting the number of keys in a bucket on the Riak cluster is not very efficient, even with the use of the MapReduce functions.

The most efficient way I have found to count the number of items is to do it on the client through the streaming API. The following example uses node-js to do this.

First install the riak-js client

```
npm install riak-js@latest
```

Then run the following on the command line to give you your count.

```
node -e "require('riak-js').getClient({ host: 'hostname', port: 8098 }).count('bucket');"
```

Comment: To provide the source: this method was [suggested by francisco treacy](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-November/006636.html) in the Riak mailing list to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me - put it into console, no further installs:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8098/mapred -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{"inputs":"THE_BUKET",
 "query":[{"map":{"language":"javascript",
                  "keep":false,
                  "source":"function(riakobj) {return [1]; }"}},
          {"reduce":{"language":"javascript",
                     "keep":true,
                     "name":"Riak.reduceSum"}}]}'
```

Comment: This is a very expensive way to calculate the number of entries in a bucket as it both lists all keys in the bucket (which is not recommended in production) and then also runs a lot of JavaScript MapReduce functions. If this however is required, a more efficient way to do this is as follows: curl -XPOST http://localhost:8098/mapred -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"inputs":"mybucket","query":[{"reduce":{"language":"erlang","module":"riak_kv_mapreduce","function":"reduce_count_inputs","arg":{"do_prereduce":true}}}]}'

Answer (score 2):

There is also a open request on features.basho.com to make this easier (because, as bennettweb pointed out, it's not the most straightforward task).

http://features.basho.com/entries/20721603-efficiently-count-keys-in-a-bucket

Upvotes, comments, etc., are encouraged.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/2i/

paragraph "Count Bucket Objects via $bucket Index"

```
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:8098/mapred
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
  -d '{"inputs":{
           "bucket":"mybucket",
           "index":"$bucket",
           "key":"mybucket"
       },
       "query":[{"reduce":{"language":"erlang",
                           "module":"riak_kv_mapreduce",
                           "function":"reduce_count_inputs",
                           "arg":{"reduce_phase_batch_size":1000}
                          }
               }]
       }'
EOF
```

reduce index is better than mapreduce data